# Sharepoint 2010 - SPSite class throws Exception

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have Created Sample Console Applciation in .Net 3.5 X64 with Sharepoint 2010 - Windows Server 2008.

It Always throws Exception, Please help me to resolve this issue

This is the Sample Code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace SharepointConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL = "http://inblr-iifw8sv03:31521/";

            try
            {
                using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(URL))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sharepoint URL Found");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // LogEvent(ex.Message, TraceEventType.Error);
                Console.WriteLine("Sharepoint URL not Found");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sharepoint URL not Found

Exception Detils

```
The Web application at http://inblr-iifw8sv03:31521/ could not be found. Verify
that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing con
tent, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the
intended application.
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: That error is what you usally get when the Platform Target is incorrect. (If you know that the URL is correct and that the machine running your code can access that url)

Comment: I **think** you want to get central administration as a site, **If yes** then try, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication centralWeb = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;

Answer (score 1):

What is the exception thrown?

Can you also make sure that both Release and Debug modes are set to "Any CPU" or "x64", not just the Release.

> Under Project Propertes --> Build--> Configuration (select Debug) and set Platform Target

(then do the same for Release)

Otherwise if you start the program from Visual Studio in Debug mode, it won't work.

Comment: Yes I tried as you said, Still Error exists

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you run your Console application on the server where SharePoint is set up?

Error tells you that SPSite cannot find a site. Try to see if you have added entry to the site in the host file:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Open it with notepad as Administrator and add IP and host name as shown in example.

Other, see if you have added bindings to the site in IIS manager: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: 1. URL is Correct ,2. Am running this Console application in Server 2008 wiht Sharepoint 2010 , Also Build the Console app in X64 in both Debug and Releae version.then Issue still coming. Please help me to resolve this....... we are stuck here for one month

Comment: Did you try this tool - http://cksdev.codeplex.com/? This has template to creta SharePoint Consol application. I know that there are some settings to set up when create console application and this tool is sets up all for you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved when I changed  "Target Framework" to ".NET Framework 3.5" in application properties of VS 2010 project. Platform Target should be  "x64" in "Build" tab for "Debug" and "Active(Debug)" configurations.